# How can I combine a mouseenter / mouseleave and dynamic setting of class in an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

How can I combine two different ways of setting class with ng-repeat?

I have the following:

```
<div class="row"
   data-ng-class="highlightclass"
   data-ng-mouseenter="highlightclass='highlight'"
   data-ng-mouseleave="highlightclass=''"
   data-ng-repeat="a in rows"
>

<div class="row"
   data-ng-class="{'t': a.correct == true, 'f': a.correct == false}"
   data-ng-mouseenter="highlightclass='highlight'"
   data-ng-mouseleave="highlightclass=''"
   data-ng-repeat="a in rows"
>
```

Both work but I do not know how to combine them. Does anyone have any ideas how this can be done? What I would like is for the class highlight to appear when the mouse is over the row in addition to the t and f classes appearing depending on the value of a.correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
<div class="row"
   data-ng-class="{'highlight': highlighted, 't': a.correct, 'f': !a.correct}"
   data-ng-mouseenter="highlighted=true"
   data-ng-mouseleave="highlighted=false"
   data-ng-repeat="a in rows"
>
```